# Changing accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Just curious but what happens if you *accept* an answer after you've already *accepted* one?

Does the original answerer lose the points and the new one gain them?  Is it even possible to change your accepted answer (it appears as though it's possible since the button isn't disabled)

Comment: (I checked meta.english, meta.stackoverflow, and the FAQ, and I couldn't find an answer at any of them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can change your accepted answer indefinitely, forever.

However, you can only do it once every 24 hours as I recall, to prevent weird rapid accept change gaming issues.

Comment: So the points actually transfer from the original accepted answerer to the newly accepted answerer?

Comment: @adv yes, subtract from old and add to new